# How to disable button when dropdown changes?

Tags: jquery

The code below does the following. A user selects a SVN branch from the dropdown. This loads another page with the associated modules inside another dropdown. It works fine and the `Continue` button is disabled when the second dropdown (`module_name`) isn't selected. However, if I go back and select a different branch from the first dropdown, the `Continue` button is active, I need it to reset to disable.

HTML code

```
<select name="branch_name" id="branch_name">
    <option value="">-- Select a branch --</option>
<?php
    foreach($results as $k) {
        echo "<option value='{$k}'>{$k}</option>";
    }
?>
</select>

<select name="module_name" id="module_name">
    <option value="">-- Select a module --</option>
<?php
    foreach($results as $k) {
        echo "<option value='{$k}'>{$k}</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

JS code

```
$(document).on('change', '#module_name', function(){
    $('#continue').prop('disabled', $('#module_name option:selected').length == '');
});

$('#branch_name').on("change", function() {
    $('#output').load('/tags/module',{branch_name: $(this).val()});
});
```

New JS Code which works

```
$(document).on('change', '#module_name', function(){
    $('#continue').prop('disabled', $(this).val() =='');
});

$('#branch_name').on("change", function() {
    $("#continue").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $('#output').load('/tags/module',{branch_name: $(this).val()});
});
```

Comment: Does `$(document).on('change', '#module_name', function(){...})` fire? I thought that the change event didn't bubble.

Comment: Maybe it was just (older versions of) IE.

Comment: Using chrome. see edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length` is a number and your test was checking if there is an `option` in the select, so it won't ever equal `''`

```
    /* checks how many eleemnts match selector, will return "0" if none exist*/
    $('#module_name option:selected').length
```

Use `val()` to see if select has a value

```
$(document).on('change', '#module_name', function(){
    $('#continue').prop('disabled', $(this).val() =='');
});
```

Comment: Damn, that was it. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Actually, I needed the following code with the second onchange (`#branch_name`). `$("#continue").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

Comment: Make sure you test in IE. Probably OK in recent version(s) but failure of the `change` event to bubble in IE was an issue for a long time.

Comment: Thanks, the good news is, it's an internal app and everyone uses Chrome. Nonetheless, good to know.

Comment: One-browser coding - lucky you.

Comment: Question, do I really need `$(document).on('change', '#module_name', function()` or can I "shorten" it with `$('#module_name').on("change", function()` ... I tried it but the `continue` button doesn't enable. Changing it back to the original enables the `continue` button when a value is selected.

Comment: acting on 2 different elements `#module_name` vs `#branch_name`. I'm not sure which is which, i just followed your code